# Is it possible to stop Angular 17 ng serve to inject /@vite/client script tag to index head?

Tags: vite, angular17

When using Angular 17 with @angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server builder under angular.json serve/builder configuration section  is injected into the head part of the intex.html page. This causes the hash value of the index.html page to differ from the calculated value from the previous build steps.

Is there any way to configure @angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server in angular.json not to inject the /@vite/client? If not. Is it possible to change the development server to say webpack (I used to work before upgrading to Angular v17)?

I'm using the standard @angular-devkit/build-angular:application builder under architect build section for the angular.json file.

I did not find any obvious options to remove this setting under the server/options section in the angular.json file. Checked open and closed issuses at angular github issues list without luck.